# eclipse ADT slowdown and error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

after updating my ADT to the latest version, i am having frequent slowdowns and crashes..

lately this error happens more frequently than not. i had to force quit it resulting to unsaved activities..

[image: ERROR]

i have already close all projects/libraries that isn't in use, its still slowing down even if there is only one project that is opened.

should i reinstall eclipse? what would happen to all of my projects and libraries? this is my first eclipse and this is the first time that this happened to me...

Comment: Did you do Help/Check for updates, after upgrading the SDK?

Comment: yes, that's what i do to update..

Comment: It's your first eclipse project, so why not give android studio a go? You could try it out during all the restarts eclipse seems to need.

Comment: @Poldie there's a bit of misunderstanding, what i mean is this is my first install of eclipse not project.. i have not installed/ reinstalled eclipse before

Answer (score 1):

Change Target SDK in your manifest to 18 for the  time being to avoid the crashes. Issue is with android-19. Wait for another update before switching back.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all errors and warnings from your layouts.
2. Make sure you are running the eclipse in admin mode (windows users)
3. Go to `your eclipse folder location -> open eclipse.ini file` then change.

   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms256m-Xmx512m

to

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6-Xms512m-Xmx1024m
```

this may help you a little bit.